# Visually scroll UIScrollView content in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

When laying out a `UIScrollView` in Interface Builder I want to be able to configure view that are larger than my screen.
Is there a way to visually scroll the content of my `UIScrollView` within my Storyboard in Interface Builder?

Comment: I am pretty sure there has to be another answer. I have already seen a ScrollView scroll in Interface Builder but just can't figure out the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Also, this exakt thing is easily possible with UITableView where you can scroll without problems if you have more cells than fit on the screen. Why not in UIScrollView?

Comment: Because some things just aren't. You can always offset Y of your content view to change what's visible so you can edit it to your likening. I'd be the first to welcome a scrollview I can scroll in IB.

Comment: Filing a Radar right now... :)

Comment: It's possible since Xcode 11 — select some view inside scroll view in the View Tree and then scroll with your touchpad.  
Vote for reopen.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't scroll it, but you can just give the scroll view a content view and make that content view as large as you need it. Auto layout (or manual configuration) will take care of the actual `contentSize` at runtime.

Comment: Setting the content size is not my problem. How do I design a view that is e.g. 1000pt high and of which only half is visible in IB?

Comment: If the view is 1000 pt high it will be completely visible in IB. Grow the view controller as much as you need to.

Comment: Here is a downloadable example project that demonstrates. The content of the scroll view is considerably taller than an iPhone. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout2/ch20p673scrollViewInNib

Comment: Okay, now I get what you're saying. Thanks, very helpful! Would you mind updating your answer with the link and an explanation about actually growing the whole _View Controller_?

Comment: I think this matter has been dealt with sufficiently on Stack Overflow that no more is needed.